# Python Combining a FOR Loop and an IF statement

Tags: python, django

I have some issues with this small piece of code:

```
for key in UserInput.objects.all():
        if UserInput.category_id == 2:
            data = {}
            data['label'] = key.input_date
            data['value'] = key.input_value
            dataSource['data'].append(data)
```

I just don't seem to get it working. The only thing I want to do is to retrieve all rows from the UserInput table which have a category_id of 2 and then execute the four data lines for each row to use in my bar chart.

I get a variety of errors. I get an Object of type date is not JSON serializable on data['label'] = key.input_date. If I replace input_date with another (string) value, my bar chart seems to work, but it shows an empty bar chart. I tried to serialize my input_date, but I get even more errors when I try to do that.

```
json_data = serializers.serialize("xml", UserInput.objects.all())
```

and

```
fields = ['input_date']
    qs = UserInput.objects.all()
    json_input_data = serializers.serialize('json', qs, fields=fields)
```

My Python knowledge doesn't reach far enough to solve this on my own.

I would prefer to sort the data to month-year instead of day-month-year, but I would understand if this is beyond the scope of my question

EDIT:
As many pointed it out in the comments, I do indeed use Django. I didn't mention it before because I thought it wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Are you working with Django? This part `UserInput.objects.all()` suggests that you do but you don't say that in any part of your question

Comment: It is hard to understand your question if 1) we don't have a copy of your codes 2) sample data.

Comment: Are you sure the category id is an `int`?

Comment: Instead of doing `if UserInput.catgory_id == 2`, you might want to do `if key.category_id == 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using Django, so you should use the [tools provided by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

```
objects_with_category_id_2 = UserInput.objects.filter(category_id=2)
for obj in objects_with_category_id_2:
     data =  {'label': obj.input_date,
              'value': obj.input_value}
     dataSource['data'].append(data)
```

Comment: It works perfectly when I use some other value than input_date, but with input_date I get an Object of type date is not JSON serializable error. Do you have any recommendations to how to fix this?